# Is there a word with the opposite meaning to "except"/"everything but"?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

Except means "everything but". Is there a single word in English that has the opposite meaning to that of "except" (an antonym of except)?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: "Except" as a preposition means *excluding*. The opposite is *including*. "Except" as a conjunction means *only*.  So, which one do you want an antonym for? (Which is why an example sentence would be nice. It would also demonstrate whether your understanding of "except" is correct.) **Or** do you want an antonym for "everything but," which does not necessarily mean "except"?

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is "including":

> Put everything on my sandwich **except** pickles.
>
> Put everything on my sandwich, **including** pickles.

You might find it useful to purchase a [thesaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesaurus) or a [dictionary of synonyms](https://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1). These books often list antonyms, too.

Comment: @δοῦλος I hate to be disagreeable, but I also think "only" is a good hypothesis. We'll have to see what the OP chooses. :)

Comment: Apparently, Oxford Dictionaries also says that [the antonym of *except* is *including*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/except).

Comment: Well it is actually unclear what the OP is asking @Damkerng T. See my comment to his post. We can't be sure his understanding is correct without a sentence demonstrating it.

Answer (score 12):

Another possible world could be "especially", depending on the context. It's roughly to mean "everything, and this in particular".

> They were all good players, **especially** this one.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematically, we might argue that if "except" is defined as "everything but", then we must have a universe *X* say, in which we want everything but except some A. So an antonym of "except" woud be "only" - we "only" want A and nothing else from *X*.

[only](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/only)

Comment: we might `argue`, not `argument` :-) but +1 for the reasoning!

Comment: Excepting that language doesn't work like logic. Plus, you are arguing for the antonym of 'everything but' and then applying it to 'except'. Your reasoning is linguistically lacking

Answer (score 1):

Another option, to describe extra elements, might be "additionally":

> Put everything on my sandwich **except** for pickles.
>
> Put everything on my sandwich, **and additionally** some pickles.

Although in normal conversation, this would usually be said in a less technical way:

> Put everything on my sandwich, and please **add** some pickles too.

Answer (score 0):

Only.
Except means "everything but"
Antonym should be "nothing but"
and that is "only"

Answer (score 0):

Always, 
Include(-ing), &
And.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. One hint to improve your answer: expand a bit. While I really appreciate short and to-the-point answers, some examples or an explaining sentence wouldn't hurt here.